# Test if a PC is reachable over network and run a task if it is, in a powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a list of  machines in  a network  and  want to know, if a machine is   network accessible.  I want to  run a command  per  machine but if machine  is not   accessible  I will get an  error,   I want  to know  if  I can run a ping  command  over each  PC  on  the   script and  capture  a true or  false if PC is  in  a network

Pseudo code

```
-Get  file name  by opening a Windows  file  search menu.
-Get  file with all  hosts to run command  on 
-Iterate over hosts 
    -run if   statement   ( if  PC   pingable  )
        -run main action command  
    -if PC not pingable  
skip  and repeat ..
```

Is there a   way  I can capture  true or false  from ping ?

Code I have so far   that works if every PC on the list is reachable

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$(Get-location)\Client-log-$(Get-date -Format "yyyyMMddTHHmmss").log"

Function Get-FileName{
  
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = Get-Location
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$Importfile = Get-FileName

$Clients = Get-Content $Importfile
Foreach($Client in $Clients){

    #inser conditional  to check if   ping is  good or bad 

    (Get-HotFix -ComputerName $Clients | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn)[-1]

    }

Stop-Transcript
```

basic idea  for this  script  is to get  the latest  KB update installed on PC

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help Test-Connection`. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks!  That was very helpful . i manage to do  what i needed with this read

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey hey i got an other question regarding this is there a more efficient way to what im doing? I mean it work now. But it takes too long to get data back

Comment: running a query across the network is always gonna be slow-ish. [*grin*] i would use `Invoke-Command` to run the `Get-HotFix` on the target systems ... and let the `I-C` call deal with non-responders. take a look at the `-ErrorVariable` parameter for some ideas on handling errors neatly.

Comment: you are welcome ... glad to have helped somewhat! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `Test-Connection` cmdlet.

You can set a variable and test whether this is true or false. Ex:

```
    if $testConnection 'do something'
```

Edit: If you use the   `Quiet` parameter, it returns a Boolean value in a System.Boolean object for each tested connection.